# My custom validation annotation is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-annotations

i have created an annotation that has features such as checking if the entered string is null or at the assigned value.But the annotation doesn't work. I don't think it does any validation on the DTO.What am I doing wrong ? I also added the valid annotation on the controller. I don't think the isValid() function works.

```java
import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {SpecificStringValueValidator.class})
@Target( {PARAMETER} )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SpecificStringValue {
    //This annotation ensures input is not null and contains no empty strings
    //Also applies maximum minimum control if specified
    //Checks if the input is of length value given.
    int value() default 0;
    int min() default -9999;
    int max() default -9999;
    String message() default "Invalid String";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SpecificStringValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SpecificStringValue,String> {

    private SpecificStringValue specificValue;
    private boolean status = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(SpecificStringValue specificValue) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(specificValue);
        this.specificValue = specificValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String s, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        String str = s;
        String noSpaceStr = str.replaceAll("\\s", "");

        //This if block work if it is requested to have a certain length.
        if(specificValue.value() != 0){
            //Check does the string contain a space character?
            if(noSpaceStr.length() == s.length() && s.isEmpty() && s.length() == specificValue.value()){
                status = true;
            }
        }
        //If there is no specific value, it checks the max min.
        else {
            //Check does the string contain a space character?
            if(noSpaceStr.length() == s.length() && s.isEmpty() ){
               //Check the minimum number
                if(specificValue.min() != -9999){
                    if(s.length() >= specificValue.min()){
                        status = true;
                    }
                }
                //Check the maximum number
                if(specificValue.max() != -9999){
                    if(s.length() <= specificValue.max()){
                        status = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

```java
public record CreateSellerRequestDTO(
@SpecificStringValue(value = 5,message = "Username cant be null") userName){}
```

```java
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody @Valid CreateSellerRequestDTO createSellerRequestDTO){
            sellerService.create(createSellerRequestDTO);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `CreateSellerRequestDTO` as a plain class (not a record) and annotate the `username` field with the `@SpecificStringValue` annotation?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but shouldn't I be able to validate with the record type? I had previously verified the record type with the annotations that spring provided.

Comment: Therefore, I should be able to verify the record type with my own annotation.

Comment: Well, record classes are in fact auto-generated classes with immutable fields and a getter-style method for each field. How do you know where (on a method or a field) is the annotation `@SpecificStringValue` placed? The target of the annotation is only `PARAMETER` so i suspect that the annotation is not propagated to the field (`userName`), which is what will trigger the validation. You should at least try to add `METHOD` and `FIELD` to the annotation targets

Comment: You are right.My problem is fixed thank you

Comment: For completeness, i posted an answer for your problem. Please, accept it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record classes are in fact auto-generated classes with immutable fields and a getter-style method for each field. How do you know where (on a method or a field) is the annotation `@SpecificStringValue` placed?

The target of the annotation is only `PARAMETER` so i suspect that the annotation is not propagated to the field (userName), which is what will trigger the validation. You should at least try to add `METHOD` and `FIELD` to the annotation targets

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to your project.

BTW, there are multiple problems in your `isValid()` method - you don't account for the case when the input string is `null` and seem to use `s.isEmpty()` instead of `!s.isEmpty()`